# jpcap: how to detect duplicate or retransmitted frames (packets)?

Tags: java, jpcap

As from title, I am using jpcap and sometimes I get duplicate or retransmitted packets: how to detect and discards such packets?

**Edit:** the code I am using is derived from

[Packet sniffer using jpcap](http://packetsnifferusingjpcap.blogspot.it/)

Comment: Please show some code rather than just blandly asking questions

Comment: @Abishek :just edited my question with code I am using